# Windows 11 Dual boot. I can only choose OS when external monitor is connected

Tags: windows, boot, multiple-monitors

I am dual booting between two Windows 11 partitions on my Lenovo X1 Yoga Gen 6 laptop and all works fine except, when I turn on the computer, I only see the partition selector if an external monitor is plugged in.

If I plug in a monitor the blue OS select screen is being displayed on the external monitor. If no external monitor is plugged in the laptop screen is blank for 15 seconds and then the primary OS starts.

Is there a way to force that OS selector screen to be displayed on the primary screen aka the built in screen on the laptop?

I boot between a personal (primary) and a work (secondary) partition and I can only get into the work partition if an external monitor is connected.

```
PS C:\> bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {5cd5554b-4766-11ec-b941-cafbb5b71011}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 15

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Personal
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {a628b2b1-d8e9-11eb-8408-ecfd1dc6bca2}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {5cd5554b-4766-11ec-b941-cafbb5b71011}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Work
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {d0edfd74-474c-11ec-8811-8a88ba32e6f2}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
PS C:\>
```

Comment: The first and only place to check settings is your BIOS. This happens way before Windows boots up. Did you check any display-related settings in BIOS?

Comment: Now you mention it. Yes, I did update the bios recently. I cannot remember if the issue started after that. I will review the bios settings. Thx

Comment: While disconnecting a monitor from a laptop is supposed to make the laptop's screen the primary display, this doesn't always work as intended; this seems to be the issue if it only occurs when the BIOS/UEFI firmware hands off to the Windows bootloader. While booted to Windows, go into the display settings and set the laptop's screen as the primary screen _(if it is already, make the external the default, then re-set the laptop's as the default)_, disconnect the monitor and reboot - if the issue resolves, boot to Windows, plug in the monitor, then reboot with monitor still plugged in to verify.

Comment: @JW0914 That actually solved the issue. Thx. If you post your advice as an answer, i will mark it as

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling the legacy OS boot menu

From an elevated command prompt type:

> bcdedit /set "{current}" bootmenupolicy legacy

hit enter and reboot.